# how can i save the result of query into html file in mysql?

Tags: mysql

When connecting to mysql server with '-H', all query result will be in html format(only on the command line console), but when i save the result into file using "select... into outfile xxx", it is not in html format in the file. How to proceed?

Comment: Is there any error message? In what format output is coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQLyog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) for this purpose. Follow simple steps...

Execute the query, from results tab, click on "Export as"(see screenshot attached), select to export as HTML, and give the file name in which you would like to export and then click on Export Button. Data will be exported.

[image: HTML layout screenshot]

You can use command line tool for each query as follows(Note: path to MySQL should be set):

I tried by first connecting with -H, and then using outfile, but it did not worked that way. It works as follows

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> -H -e "query" <database> > <Filepath>

e.g.

mysql -umyusername -pmypassword -H -e "SELECT * from mydb.mytable" mydb > e:\test_html.html
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks, but if i want to use command on linux shell or windows cmd, how should do？

Comment: I have edited my answer, just have a look at it...